# How to add Right to left c++

Tags: c++

I have an issue with right to left text (Hebrew language).

I used this to support Hebrew but i have an issue with Right to left.

When im saying "Hello" in Hebrew it saying it in the opposite direction "olleH"

This is what i use to force the .dll file to support the Hebrew charset (1255).

```
BYTE CHAT_HOOK[] = { 0xB8, 0xE3, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90 };
MemoryCpy(0x009D0120, CHAT_HOOK, sizeof(CHAT_HOOK));
SetDword((0x009D0120 + 1), 1255);

enter code here
```

Does anyone know what i need to add here in order to fix this issue.?

Thank you,
Daniel.